# Select how often a column value occurs within a pre-defined range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select the number of occurrences of values of the [price] field in a custom defined range:

My price ranges are:

```
< 10  
10-20  
20-50  
> 50
```

So if prices would be 3,4,11 and 20 the result would be:

```
< 10 (2)  
10-20 (1)  
21-50 (1)  
> 50 (0)
```

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[price] [decimal](8, 0) NULL,
[createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[products] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_products_createdate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdate]
GO
```

Comment: What have you tried and what did not work? Also where would you like "custom ranges" to be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With 
Categorized as
(
 Select 
 CASE When Price < 10 Then '<10'
      When Price >= 10 and Price < 20 Then '[10-20)'
      Else '>20'
 END as Category
 From SomeTable
)
Select Category, Count(*) From Categorized
Group By Category
```

Something *like* this.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
;WITH Ranges_CTE ([sequence], [range], [lower_limit], [upper_limit]) AS
  (
   SELECT 1,'<10', 0, 9
    UNION
    SELECT 2,'10-20', 10, 19
    UNION
    SELECT 3, '20-50', 20, 50
    UNION
    SELECT 4, '>50', 51, 1000
   )

SELECT r.range, count(p.id) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM ranges_cte r
LEFT OUTER JOIN products p ON p.price BETWEEN r.lower_limit AND r.upper_limit
GROUP BY r.range, r.sequence
ORDER BY r.sequence
```

Note that your ranges are ambiguous.  You show `20-50` in one place and `21-50` elsewhere.  The data seems to indicate that `20-50` is correct.  But, then price 20 would fit in `10-20` and `20-50`.  I assumed `10-20` had an upper limit of 19.